# Django: Serializing models in a nested data structure?

Tags: database, django, serialization, django-models

It's easy to serialize models in an iterable:

```
def _toJSON(models):
    return serializers.serialize("json", models, ensure_ascii=False)
```

What about when I have something more complicated:

```
[
(Model_A_1, [Model_B_1, Model_B_2, Model_B_3]),
(Model_A_2, [Model_B_3, Model_B_4, Model_B_5, Model_B_59]),
(Model_A_3, [Model_B_6, Model_B_7]),
]
```

I tried serializing each model as it was added to the structure, then serializing the whole thing with `simplejson.dumps`, but that causes the JSON defining each model to be escaped.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if my proposal is a 'better way' but it worked for me for some cases when custom json format was required.

The idea is to create some django template that will create json in a format you need (probably couple of for loops). This template + conext with your models structure should give json you are looking for.

Of course there are some drawbacks here that need to be mentioned. It would be a pain to deserialize such json in python, it might not be so fast as other solutions and probably others. But in case if this is not a problem for you, I think this solution is quite handy and can help you move forward with your project.